# How to fix selecting text and scrolling stops half way with M1 trackpad?

Tags: trackpad, macos

The method used to select text without scrolling:

1. click the index finger on the touchpad
2. Use the middle finger to move the cursor to the end of the selection

The method used to select text with scrolling:

1. click the index finger on the touchpad
2. Use the middle and fourth (ring) finger to scroll up and down
3. Use the middle finder to move the cursor to the end of the selection once scrolled to the correct portion of the page

The experience faced when using the select text with scrolling:

- After an initial scroll down, scrolling stops and no longer has an effect. While the index finger is still down the middle and ring finger scrolling motion does not result in a scroll down.
- Starting an initial scroll - the mission control (swipe up with 3 fingers) action starts showing
- After an initial scroll up, scrolling stops and no longer has an effect. While the index finger is still down - the middle and ring finger scrolling motion does not results in a scroll up.

Mac details:

- MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2021)
- version 12.6

How can this issue where selecting text and scrolling stops half way with M1 trackpad - be fixed?

Comment: Seems that it does not focus on the window after the first scroll anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the trick is to click with your index finger and move it slightly to start a selection, then put your middle and ring finger on the track pad together and begin a scroll up and down. You basically don't want to confuse the track pad into thinking you're trying to do 3-finger swipe up or down and instead be as clear as possible in the gesture that you're selecting and then scrolling in that order.

The most important thing is to make sure you're selecting and moving the cursour with your index finger, not the middle finger.